# Adding C++ snippets to Jetbrains Clion

Tags: c++, emacs, clion, jetbrains-ide

I am looking for yasnippets (for emacs) like C++ code snippets feature in Jetbrains Clion.

How to get this in Jetbrains Clion?

Some example snippets from yasnippets in emacs (to give an idea of what I am looking for):

main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    return 0;
}
```

for-loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){                                                                            
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know? Yes, the world if full of smart people.

Comment: figured it out. Its exactly as in yasnippets. Type the first few letters of the keyword. The autocomplete suggestions list will come. Scroll to your desired keyword and hit Tab. And the snippet will come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, read about [live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.2/live-templates.html) and [blog record](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/06/code-generation-with-clion/). Seems it is exactly that you need. We already have [for-loop] live template. There are really two: [for]/[iter]. Please, try with complition!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
  for<Ctrl+Space or choose from drop-down list>  
}
```

=>

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
  for (int i = 0; i < ; ++i) {

  }
}
```